How to map values of elements in Outlook Web plugin's manifest to keys in a json file?
So I have an Outlook javascript plugin XML manifest whereby its Description is translated.
<OfficeApp>
  <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
  ... 
  <Description DefaultValue="Watch YouTube videos referenced in the emails you receive without leaving your email client.">
   <Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="Visualisez les vidéos YouTube référencées dans vos courriers électronique directement depuis Outlook."/>
  </Description>
  ...
</OfficeApp>

I would like to move this value to a json file located in src\shared\i18n\locale-fr.json
which will have this content
{
  ...
  "Watch YouTube videos referenced in the emails you receive without leaving your email client.": "Visualisez les vidéos YouTube référencées dans vos courriers électronique directement depuis Outlook."
}

And map it to Description element in manifest, something like this
<OfficeApp>
  <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
  ... 
  <Description DefaultValue="{values."Watch YouTube videos referenced in the emails you receive without leaving your email client."}">
  </Description>
  ...
</OfficeApp>

Yes, the manifest above is wrong but I hope you get the idea.
The reason is because this .json file is used as translation locale file for all other strings in my Outlook plugin code. Hence, I would like to centralize all translations into this file, including the strings in the manifest.
How do I achieve this?
Note:I had looked into <ExtendedOverrides> but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it work.

Manifest is the plain XML file and does not have any preprocessing before it is loaded into Outlook. You cannot have any dynamic parts in this file.
If you would like to "centralize" your translations inside the json file you are using for your add-on, you may consider pre-processing the manifest.xml file during the build time of your application. As a result of this build, you would get a plane xml file with embedded translation. For example, you may use the facility of your CI/CD builds, gitlab, webpack processing, etc. Simply replace the placeholders in your manifest.xml file with translated values from your resources' json file.
